# I need to clear the result data in Angular

Tags: angular

In this i am showing the result below the input field after clicking the scan button. Now i need to clear the result when i clear the domainUrl(which is in input field).

app.component.html:

```
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">

  <div class="row col-md-4">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-n5">
  <a href="https://logo.ai/" target="_blank"><img 
   src="./assets/image/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group d-flex align-items-baseline">
  <p class="col-12 mb-0 pb-2">loreum ipsum....<a 
   href="link" target="_blank">loreum</a> ipsum</p>

  <input type="url" class="form-control pt-1" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Enter your Target Url"
       [(ngModel)]="domainUrl"  aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" (change)="inputChanged=true" >
<div class="input-group-prepend m-0">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " (click)="scanDomain()"
          [disabled]="(isLoading || ((!domainUrl || !domainUrl.length) && 
   !inputChanged) || (isLoading && !inputChanged)) ">{{submitBtntext}}
     <i *ngIf="isLoading"  class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-x"></i>

  </button>
   </div>
  </div>

  <span *ngIf="this.result" class="pt-2 mt-2">{{ this.result.result}}</span>
 </div>

  </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a new `onChange` method that is invoked on `keyup` event and clears the `this.result` variable when the `this.domainUrl` is `empty` or `null`.

Your markup would look as follows:

```
  <input type="url" class="form-control pt-1" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Enter your Target Url"
       [(ngModel)]="domainUrl"  aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" (change)="onChange()" (keyup)="onChange()" >
```

Typescript addition:

```
  onChange(): void {
    this.inputChanged = true;
    if (!this.domainUrl) {
      this.result = {};
    }
  }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v2qsr5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It is working only  when i clear the url and click on outside of the field .

Comment: @Bhargavi I have updated the answer to use keyup event. Please see if it helps now.